# Trying to login with google returns permission denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following security rules for my database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've also implemented a google login via Firebase Auth. It works as long as those rules aren't enabled.

Having them enabled I get the following error:

> premission_denied

**I assume that I try to fetch data, before the login has finished. You can find the code below.**

How do I solve this issue?

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed logging into Google: ", error)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged into Google.")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (acc, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to create User with Google: ", error)
            return
        }

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        databaseRef.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("\(uid)") {
                print("Data found.")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                vc.readLeasing()
                vc.readData()
            } else {
                self.upDataToDatabase(from: user)
            }

        })

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        defaults.set(user.profile.name, forKey: "name")

        logInViaGoogle = true
        defaults.set(logInViaGoogle, forKey: "logInViaGoogle")

        print("Successfully created user with Google.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't listen to all users you need

```
databaseRef.child("users/\(uid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
  if snapshot.exists() {
      print("Data found.")
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
      vc.readLeasing()
      vc.readData()
  } else {
      self.upDataToDatabase(from: user)
  }         
})
```